# Do I really need to upgrade a Magento 1.7.0.2 site to use a template that is meant for 1.8.x - 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, template, theme, third-party-module

I bought a template that I realized after the fact is meant for 1.8 or 1.9 versions, but I am wondering how much of an issue this is. I am a newbie to Magento and I really am hesitating on upgrading because it sounds involved. This particular one is set up for multi site and uses the Enterprise Edition so don't know if I would have to purchase that too in order to upgrade? I appreciate any guidance, my searching hasn't turned up any results on this type of question.

Comment: Depends on how backwards compatible they made the template. 1.9.x.x uses formkeys in the front end and if they don't have logic to detect and use the proper link per the version that it's installed on, the template may not work. It's a question you need to ask the developer that created the template.

Comment: I removed the [tag:magento-enterprise] tag because 1.7.0.2 is obviously not EE

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Fabian - I was going to do that just now, but you type so fast!!!!

Comment: I bought it from TemplateMonster, so not sure if they will be able to tell me or not. If not at least you have given me what I might need to find and change if I run into problems.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't - the versions you list in your questions reference Magento Community Edition, not Magento Enterprise Edition.  The most recent version of Magento EE is 1.14.1 and Magento CE is 1.9.2

Normally, your themes will list the versions supported of EACH, though you may see the CE version more prominently displayed because it i more popularly used, being free.

[Here's a rough timeline on the version history from Shero Designs](http://sherodesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/magento-throughout-the-years-infographic-4-16-14.pdf), though it stops at December of 2014 and doesn't include the latest EE 1.14.X or CE 1.9.X releases from 2015.

You should definitely not upgrade just for a template, more likely than not you can buy another similar one for less than $100 and any upgrade will likely take more than that in time spent.  To be fair, though, upgrading from 1.7.X -> 1.9.X isn't THAT tough, though the 1.9.1.1 and 1.9.2 releases make some pretty substantial changes in Email handling and ACL's for Admin Components that can take some time to sort out.  If you DO decide to upgrade, I'd start by going to 1.9.1.0 and stabilizing that code base after installing the required security patches before moving to quickly forward, at least if you're going to attempt it on your own.

The only issue you may need to deal with in the 1.9.1.0 releases is the deprecation of support for php 5.3 (5.4 is minimum officially supported, though to be honest we've seen it run ok on 5.3) and the additional of form keys.  Neither of which are terribly tough to work around and since you're already familiar with Stack Exchange you know where to come to for help ;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Good to know, I assumed that it had to be EE when I was trying to figure out what it was from the features. I thought I had seen the multi site feature only available for it. I guess I might try adding the template and activate it to see if any problems come up. Thanks again!

Comment: Is the template one that you designed in house or one that was bought from a vendor?  If a vendor sold it, they will tell you specifically what EE versions are supported by the template.  Paste the template and vendor info in your question & I'll help you confirm it now.

Comment: What version of EE are you running on this site?

Answer (score 0):

If the theme contains its own templates in `template/checkout/onepage`, it will probably not work, because in `1.8` the checkout has undergone a remarkable technical change, where all steps are loaded dynamically and not preloaded on page load as before.